# How to easy setup reliable font with modern symbols and emoji support on void-linux?

Tags: fonts, desktop-environment, fontconfig, void-linux, emoji

I was a Ubuntu Desktop user from long years. I changed for void-linux because the Unity desktop env does not fit well with i3 and I want a more personalized desktop settings.

The setup works well, but I have issues with fonts: Some symbols and the emojis are badly or not rendered.

**Google Chromium**

[image]

**URxvt**

[image]

**VIM with vim-airline**

[image]

I found a lot of solutions, not directly related with void-linux, but they are all quite complex and so far, not really working (simple font install with xbps, font-config, i3 config...).

I like the more granulated configuration I have, but I also would like to have a good X setup with recommended font like I had with Unity.

What is the easy and recommended way to achieve that?

EDIT: I just tried again to install `noto-fonts-emoji` and reboot. Now I have emoji rendering inside Chromium and Firefox but still not in terminal. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Setting Your terminal emulator to use that font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so urxvt does not seem to support emoji: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/9u681d/how_to_use_emoji_fonts_with_urxvtunicode/e91wttn

I switched to terminator and will look for termite when it will be officially available under void.